# Cannot override ConstraintValidator default message in Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am having issues with overriding the default ConstraintValidator message when using Spring validation.

I have a custom messages.properties file that contains the following values:

```
NotNull=This field is mandatory
BankHoliday=You cannot select a bank holiday
```

My annotation for BankHoliday is as follows:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = BankHolidayValidator.class)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BankHoliday {

    String message() default "{BankHoliday}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

My validator is as follows:

```
public class BankHolidayValidator implements ConstraintValidator<BankHoliday, Date> {

@Override
public void initialize(BankHoliday bankHoliday) { }

@Override
public boolean isValid(Date date, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {

    if(date == null) {
        cxt.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        cxt.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{NotNull}").addConstraintViolation();
        return false;
    } else if (isBankHoliday(date)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

My model is annotated with the @BankHoliday annotation:

```
@BankHoliday
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yy")
private Date desiredBookingDate;
```

My controller looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/new/request", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String putNewRequest(@Valid @ModelAttribute("request") Request request, BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, Object> map) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

        // return them back

    } else {

        // process the request
    }
}
```

However, when the user does not populate this field, the error message they see is "You cannot select a bank holiday" instead of "This field is mandatory". Having stepped through the code I can see that the cxt.disableDefaultConstraintViolation() line is definitely being called and the {NotNull} constraint validation is being added, but the user always sees the default message.

I have tried replacing "{NotNull}" with "A test message" and this does not work either. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this isn't working?

Comment: Have you tried your example with pure Bean Validation? Basically create a Validator instance and validate two different instances which should return different messages. I am basically wondering whether the problem occurs in Bean Validation (aka Hibernate Validator) or within the Spring integration (maybe the messages are cached!?). That said, I agree with http://stackoverflow.com/a/25596487/115835 - it would be more in the spirit of Bean Validation to use constraint composition instead of dynamically changing the message - http://goo.gl/pLg8Hi

Comment: I've looked into constraint composition and this is much more suitable, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into my own code (which is working) and only one difference is that you didn't invoke `addNode()` method, so I suggest to invoke it:

```
cxt.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
cxt.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{NotNull}")
   .addNode("desiredBookingDate")
   .addConstraintViolation();
```

But, IMHO, you are going to wrong direction: validator should be responsible only for one type of validation. To mark field as mandatory it's better to use `@NotNull` annotation instead. You, probably, will face up with another issue: empty string will always pass such constraint. And to fix that, in Spring, you should use `StringTrimmerEditor` with `emptyAsNull` = `true` parameter which turns empty string to `null` value before validation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried `cxt.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{NotNull}").addNode("desiredBookingDate").addConstraintViolation();` but I now get an exception "JSR-303 validated property 'desiredBookingDate. desiredBookingDate' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding". Also, `addNode()` is now deprecated so I tried its replacement `addPropertyNode()` but that failed with the same error.

Comment: It's another error and it means that object with desiredBookingDate property doesn't have corresponding setter (`void setDesiredBookingDate(Date)`).

Answer (score 2):

A bit late probably.. but I'll post my answer for others..

Apparently it has something to do with the name of the default message constant.

```
{BankHoliday} could be replaced with {bank.holiday} (or any other key) and it will work.
```

Of course.. rename the message key in the properties file as well.. It doesn't like the messages which have exact name as the interface itself.

Comment: It worked, but add {bank.holiday} message in ValidationMessages.properties instead of messages.properties